# Vertical center Radio input with Semantic-ui

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using Sematic-ui to style a web page, in the page I have Radio input, but I don't want just a simple text label!

I try to use Semantic Header as a label content to Radio input, but the radio is not vertical middle of the line!

With some change on css I make the radio to be on the middle of line but the black dot inside the radio circle (that's show which Radio is selected) go wrong position!

Here is my work about solving this problem without success:

```
.field label {
  display: flex !important;
}

.field label::before {
  margin: auto 10px;
  position: relative !important;
}
```

Link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/talulo/edit?html,css,output)

Maybe there is a better solution for this situation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
.ui.radio.checkbox label:before, .ui.radio.checkbox label:after {
  top: 20px;
}
```

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jedizosope/edit?html,css,output)

The appropriate way would be to re-write the whole css and use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).